# abnormal resizing of java.awt.Image on using getImage() and getScaledInstance()

Tags: java, image, swing, rmi, imageicon

I m making a `java rmi based application` where i pass and receive an ImageIcon object from the server...
(the image is stored in a separate URL in server)

**The function involves the following....**

```
        1.  Getting the image from the server at first....(on button press A)
        2.  Replacing it with a image file in the client[optional]....(on button press B)
        3.  Remove the image with a default image[optional]....(on button press C) 
        4.  Sending it back to the Server....................(On button press D).....
```

**Here the image is displayed in a**`jlabel` **called**`img_label`

The codes i've used are as follows.....

**Variables used**

```
                   java.awt.Image img;
                   javax.swing.ImageIcon CurrentImageIcon;
                   javax.swing.ImageIcon DefaultImageIcon;
                   // CurrentImageIcon contains the image to be displayed in the img_label....
                   // img is used for copying as well for scaling......
                   // DefaultImageIcon holds the default Image......
```

**On Button Press A**

```
                   img = temp.getImage();
                   CurrentImageIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
                   // Assuming temp holds the ImageIcon taken from the server.......

                   img=img.getScaledInstance(83,85 , Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
                   img_label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
                   img_label.revalidate();
                   img_label.repaint();
```

**On Button Press B**

```
                   String url_text = jTextField.getText(); // taking the url frm the field.....
                   CurrentImageIcon = new ImageIcon(url_text);

                   img=CurrentImageIcon.getImage();
                   img=img.getScaledInstance(83,85 , Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
                   img_label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
                   img_label.revalidate();
                   img_label.repaint();
```

**On Button Press C**

```
                   img = DefaultImageIcon.getImage();
                   CurrentImageIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
                   img=img.getScaledInstance(83,85 , Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
                   img_label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
                   img_label.revalidate();
                   img_label.repaint();
```

**On Button Press D**

```
                   // ImagetoSend is an ImageIcon to be sent to the Server.....
                   ImagetoSend = CurrentImageIcon;
                   CurrentImageIcon = null;
```

Now the problem i m getting is a weird one......
**The image is getting embedded as i wanted on repainting when i click this button........**

`But when i download the recently uploaded image next time on Button press A....it is displayed either magnified or reduced to size even though i included the getScaledInstance method....`
like this...

[image: When i click the image. It embedds correctly] 
[image]

The image i am handling is a jpg image....
I even checked the image at Server directory.....No size change has occured on that file which was uploaded from client to server. But the change is observed when it is downloaded and embedded to the jlabel...
***Can Anyone help me to sort out this issue...??***

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). I tried to understand your question, but honestly I am completely confused as to what you are doing and what the problem is (maybe that's just me since 3 people up-voted your question).

Comment: @GuillaumePolet the problem is this much...friend.....i just downloaded an image through rmi.....i changed the image through browse button and send back the changed image back to the server......the problem is `although the actual image of server and client are same..(correct as it was before)...the changed image...when i downloaded it the second time....it got the image resized (enlarged or minimized)`

Comment: If nobody gives you hints or answers, I can only encourage you to read [this](http://sscce.org) and post an SSCCE.

Comment: An SSCCE would help a lot, but from the code snippets that you posted, it looks like you are displaying a scaled version of the image, but sending the unscaled version to the server.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek it's getting scaled abnormally the next time i load it from server.....plz..help..since..it's hard to post an SSCCE regarding this...and so far..what i've provided is the just method i've used i.e using `new ImageIcon()` and `getImage()`

Comment: @akp not post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) getScaledInstance is pretty asynchronous, nobody knows your ....

Comment: @akp Just for you to know, although you are using client/server communication, trying to make an SSCCE is likely to: 1) Let you find if the problem is on the client or on the server 2) Trying to reproduce the problem, it is likely that you will find the cause of your original problem. Cheers and good luck. 3) If you get to an SSCCE and still can sort it out, we will be glad to help you and I am betting that there is a 95% chance that we'll find your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow it is getting scaled down twice.  Either you scale it down then send it to the server where it is scaled down, or the both button clicks scale it.  Eliminate the scale down code on the server side and see what happens.